# MySQL - Split up INSERT in to 2 queries maybe

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an INSERT query which looks like:

```
$db->Query("INSERT INTO `surfed` (user, site) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$id."')");
```

Basically I want to insert just like the above query but if the site is already submitted by another user I don't want it to then re-submit the same `$id` in to the site column.  But multiple users can view the same site and all users need to be in the same row as the site that they have viewed which causes the surfed table to have 10s of thousands of inserts which dramatically slows down the site.

Is there any way to maybe split up the insert in some way so that if a site is already submitted it won't then submit it again for another user.  Maybe there's a way to use UPDATE so that there isn't an overload of inserts?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have a sites table? Typically in a *normalized* relational database you would have a `users`, `sites`, and then the `surfed` table.

Comment: Yes I have all of them as separate tables too, but this is just a table of the surfed table

Comment: Why are trying to prevent duplicate records in the `surfed` table?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to do it would be setting up a stored procedure which executes a SELECT to check if the user-site-combination is already in the table. If not, you execute the insert statement. If that combination already exist, you're done and don't execute the insert.

Check out the manual on stored procedures 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Well once a user has surfed a certain site it does the INSERT above and then that user-site combination won't be inserted again anyway because they won't be able to view that site again.  That isn't the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to know whether you actually inserted a line, you can use `INSERT IGNORE ...`.

```
$db->Query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `surfed` (user, site) VALUES('".$data['id']."', '".$id."')");
```

But this assumes that you have a unique key defined for the columns.

`IGNORE` here will ignore the Integrity constraint violation error triggered by attempting to add the same unique key twice.

The MySQL Reference Manual on the INSERT syntax has some informations on that http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a conditional statement that asks whether the id already exists then if it does update otherwise insert